# Kawasaki Z750S weird electrical problem when starting, any idea what could be the problem ?

Tags: motorcycle, starting, power, kawasaki

I have a 2005 Kawasaki Z750s and this weekend I was on a ride and stopped at a rest stop, and when I decided to leave, I turned the ignition on, pressed the kill switch on and the start switch and everything seemed normal for a second and then it just lost all electric power. After a few times turning the ignition on and off, I disconnected the battery, then connected it back and all of a sudden the bike started normally. I was riding it the rest of the day and the next day, did about 500km all together with no sign of problems.
Anyone had any similar experiences, is it a sign of a more serious problem, loose wiring, bad fuse ? But the problem hasn't occured since, bike works normally.

Comment: No way to know for sure, but it likely was a loose/bad battery connection.

Comment: maybe it was, since the bike fired up normally after I disconnected and then connected the battery again, very confusing incident,
hopefully someone else can shed some light about it